# SQL Insert with subquery

Tags: t-sql

I have a sql statement which is a routine insert of two values into a table (values meaning fields). These are ints/nvarchars.

However, for the 3rd field of the table (which can be null), I want to insert the max number of rows in the table + 1. How can I do this?

EDIT:

Table is as such

```
Postcode  Active ID
NULL       1      14
```

Comment: I can help to you, but please, write a sample of data: T1, T2 an T3.

Comment: This sounds like a "roll-your-own" identity field, which is a **BAD IDEA**

Comment: @JNK perhaps he wants to store the number of rows (which isn't necessarily the same as the max identity value) at the time of the insert.

Comment: What do you mean by "max number of rows"? Do you want to store the current rowcount in a field at the time of the insert?

Comment: @DavidLively - his edit tells us that's an `ID` field which seems to support my guess

Comment: @JNK Nice catch - I hadn't noticed the column name before.

Comment: @DavidLively - He just added it

Comment: @DavidLively - your answer was good, you just needed to add a note about the limitation.

Comment: He'll have problems using the 'ROW' as he'll delete row 5 and he'll end up with multiple 6's on the next insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows you how it can be done and what trouble you can get into if you need ID to be a unique value in the table. There are more situations where you might end up with duplicates. One would be that two users add rows to the table at the same time.

```
declare @T table(Postcode varchar(5), Active bit, ID bigint)

insert into @T (Postcode, Active, ID)
select '1111', 1, count(*)+1
from @T

insert into @T (Postcode, Active, ID)
select '2222', 0, count(*)+1
from @T

delete from @T where Postcode = '1111'

insert into @T (Postcode, Active, ID)
select '3333', 0, count(*)+1
from @T

select *
from @T
```

Result:

```
Postcode Active ID
-------- ------ --------------------
3333     0      2
2222     0      2
```

If you need the values to be unique you should use an [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column instead. Perhaps even make it a primary key or at least add a unique constraint on the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are working with SQL Server, since you have not specified otherwise.

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (col1, col2, col3)
        VALUES  (15, 'info', 1 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_1))
```

You should know that this will add to the expense of the insertion operation.